# Should statues be worshipped based on Veda?

Tags: scripture, gods, practice

"Andhatama pravishanti ye asambhuti mupaste"

"They enter darkness, those who worship the natural elements" (Air, Water, Fire, etc.). "They sink deeper in darkness, those who worship ***sambhuti."***
[Yajurveda 40:9]

Sambhuti means created things, for example table, chair, idol, etc.

Comment: Tou do not worship the statue, you worship God through the statue.

Comment: See https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/48465/eco-friendly-ganesha-idol/48482#48482